# Link to JQuery Mobile Pages

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Good afternoon, I am trying to create a Mobile web app through Jquery and I am trying to link the pages in the footer.

I think I have coded it correctly from watching tutorial videos and if I have'nt, I know its going to be something stupid, that I have forgotten.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="../jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 

<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
 <div data-role="headerimg">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
 </div>
    
  <div data-role="content">
    
    
    <a href="#page" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Home</a>
    <a href="#page2" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Tickets</a>
 <a href="#page3" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Shop</a>
 <a href="#page4" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Photos</a>
    <a href="#page5" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Join Us</a>
 <a href="#page6" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">More</a>
 
    </div><!-- footer -->

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
 </div>
    <H1>TICKETS</H1>
 <div data-role="content"> 
  Content  
 </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
 
     </div><!-- footer -->

  
 </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
        <H1>SHOP</H1>
 <div data-role="content"> 
  Content  
 </div>
 
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    
    </div><!-- footer -->

<div data-role="page" id="page4">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
        <H1>PHOTOS</H1>
<div data-role="content"> 
  Content  
</div>

 <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    </div><!-- footer -->


<div data-role="page" id="page5">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
        <H1>JOIN US</H1>
<div data-role="content"> 
  Content  
 </div>
 
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    </div><!-- footer -->


<div data-role="page" id="page6">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
        <H1>MORE</H1>
 <div data-role="content">
   <ul data-role="listview">
     <li><a href="#">About<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tickets<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Facebook<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Twitter<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Instagram<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Email<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
      </ul> 
    
 </div>
  
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
  </div><!-- footer -->
        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was some overlapped and unclosed tags.
Also, do not used outdated jquery libraries if possible.
Maybe something like this should help:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
    <!-- link href="../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script src="../jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page">
 <div data-role="header">
      <div data-role="headerimg">
        <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt="" />
      </div>
 </div>
      <div data-role="content">
      <a href="#page" data-role="button" >Home</a> 
      <a href="#page2" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Tickets</a> 
      <a href="#page3" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Shop</a> 
      <a href="#page4" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Photos</a> 
      <a href="#page5" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Join Us</a> 
      <a href="#page6" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">More</a>
   </div>
      <!-- footer -->
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="mainFooter"><h1>Footer p1</h1></div>
      <!-- footer -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
      <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt="" />
  <h1>TICKETS</h1>
      </div>
     
      <div data-role="content">Content</div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="mainFooter" ><h1>Footer p2</h1></div>
      <!-- footer -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page3">
      <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt="" />
        <h1>SHOP</h1>
        </div>
      <div data-role="content">Content</div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h1>Footer p3</h1></div>
      <!-- footer -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page4">
      <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt="" />
        <h1>PHOTOS</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">Content</div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h1>Footer p4</h1></div>
      <!-- footer -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page5">
      <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt="" />
        <h1>JOIN US</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">Content</div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h1>Footer p5</h1></div>
      <!-- footer -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page6">
      <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt="" />
        <h1>MORE</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
          <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tickets</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Facebook</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Twitter</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Instagram</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Email</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
     <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" ><h1>Footer p6</h1></div>
  </div>
      <!-- footer -->
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed many  `</div>` tag.Corrected version of your code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
 <div data-role="headerimg">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
 </div>
    
  <div data-role="content">
    
    
    <a href="#page" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Home</a>
    <a href="#page2" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Tickets</a>
 <a href="#page3" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Shop</a>
 <a href="#page4" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Photos</a>
    <a href="#page5" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Join Us</a>
 <a href="#page6" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">More</a>
 
    </div><!-- footer -->
 </div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
  <H1>TICKETS</H1>
 </div>
    
 <div data-role="content"> 
  Content  
 </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
 
     </div><!-- footer -->

  
 </div>


<div data-role="page" id="page3">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
        <H1>SHOP</H1>
  </div>
 <div data-role="content"> 
  Content  
 </div>
 
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    
    </div><!-- footer -->
 </div>

<div data-role="page" id="page4">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
        <H1>PHOTOS</H1>
  </div>
<div data-role="content"> 
  Content  
</div>

 <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    </div><!-- footer -->
 </div>


<div data-role="page" id="page5">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
        <H1>JOIN US</H1>
  </div>
<div data-role="content"> 
  Content  
 </div>
 
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    </div><!-- footer -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page6">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
        <H1>MORE</H1>
  </div>
 <div data-role="content">
   <ul data-role="listview">
     <li><a href="#">About<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tickets<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Facebook<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Twitter<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Instagram<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Email<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
      </ul> 
    
 </div>
  
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
  </div><!-- footer -->
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
 <div data-role="headerimg">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
 </div>
    
  <div data-role="content">
    
    
    <a href="#page" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Home</a>
    <a href="#page2" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Tickets</a>
 <a href="#page3" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Shop</a>
 <a href="#page4" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Photos</a>
    <a href="#page5" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Join Us</a>
 <a href="#page6" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">More</a>
 
    </div><!-- footer -->
 </div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
  <H1>TICKETS</H1>
 </div>
    
 <div data-role="content"> 
  Content  
 </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
 
     </div><!-- footer -->

  
 </div>


<div data-role="page" id="page3">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
        <H1>SHOP</H1>
  </div>
 <div data-role="content"> 
  Content  
 </div>
 
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    
    </div><!-- footer -->
 </div>

<div data-role="page" id="page4">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
        <H1>PHOTOS</H1>
  </div>
<div data-role="content"> 
  Content  
</div>

 <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    </div><!-- footer -->
 </div>


<div data-role="page" id="page5">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
        <H1>JOIN US</H1>
  </div>
<div data-role="content"> 
  Content  
 </div>
 
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    </div><!-- footer -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page6">
 <div data-role="header">
  <img src="../images/SoulTrainHeaderNew.jpg" width="100%" height="80" alt=""/>
        <H1>MORE</H1>
  </div>
 <div data-role="content">
   <ul data-role="listview">
     <li><a href="#">About<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tickets<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Facebook<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Twitter<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Instagram<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Email<span class="ui-li-count"></span></a></li>
      </ul> 
    
 </div>
  
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
  </div><!-- footer -->
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologises, I uploaded the wrong HTML text.

Sorry